# Possible to get bandwidth used by S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Does `boto3` in python support querying how much bandwidth is used (in bytes) by a particular S3 Bucket?

Comment: sum the stats that this endpoint returns --> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects

Comment: @aws_apprentice Thank you for your comment. But I said `bandwidth` not `storage` (e.g. how many times it has been read multiplied by its size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html):

> To track requests for access to your bucket, you can enable **server access logging**. Each access log record provides details about a single access request, such as the requester, bucket name, request time, request action, response status, and an error code, if relevant.

The logs are output to Amazon S3 (there is a delay involved). You could then process the logs files using Python. I like using Amazon Athena to run queries on the logs.

See: [Analyze Access Logs Using Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/)